# SSL Errors on iOS

Tags: ssl, https, apple-ios, namecheap

My website https://bitmagi.com is failing to load for iOS users at a pretty high rate.  Most people are getting  the "..could not establish a secure connection..." error.  I bought a cheapo positivessl cert from namecheap not sure if that is the issue.  I had a support chat with namecheap last night and they said everything is configured correctly on my end.  When I test my site through ssllabs.com it shows that iOS is passing:
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=bitmagi.com&s=45.79.3.6

I can't figure out what the heck is going on.

debian stretch 9.13
nginx 1.10.3

Comment: You should [fix](https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/) all the problems with your TLS configuration.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelHampton your link helped me fix it!  How do i mark your comment as the solution?

Comment: You should [write your own answer](/help/self-answer) that tells the specifics of how you solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this based off the suggested link from @MichaelHampton:
https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/

The specific lines that fixed it were:

```
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
```